Fedex-How to define SpecialServicesRequested SignatureOption for FedexRest
I'm using the library https://github.com/WhatArmy/FedexRest to create a fedex shipment.
I don't know how to use SIGNATURE_OPTION
$this->request
    ->setRecipients(
        (new Person)
            ->setPersonName($this->recipient->name)
            ->setPhoneNumber($this->recipient->phone_number)
            ->setCompanyName($this->recipient->company_name)
            ->withAddress(
                (new Address())
                    ->setCity($this->recipient->city)
                    ->setStreetLines($this->recipient->address)
                    ->setCountryCode($this->recipient->country)
                    ->setPostalCode($this->recipient->postal_code)
            )
    )
    ->setLineItems((new Item())
        ->setSequenceNumber(1)
        ->setItemDescription('Product 1')
        ->setWeight(
            (new Weight())
                ->setValue(1)
                ->setUnit(WeightUnits::_KILOGRAM)
        )
        ->setDimensions((new Dimensions())
            ->setWidth(15)
            ->setLength(10)
            ->setHeight(15)
            ->setUnits(LinearUnits::_CENTIMETER)
        )
    )
    // Set signature options here
    
    
    ->request();

How to use Signature option DIRECT or ADULT_ONLY

Do you still need assistance with the signature handling?
